# Simple Symbol identification python

Tags: python, syntax-error

This is relating to an error i keep getting from Coderbyte "Simple Symbols".  I'm trying to identify if a character in a string has specific characters in front and behind it. What I wrote works in my terminal, but I keep getting the same error from Coderbyte.

I'm a total noob and my code is not elegant at all. I know that, I'm more concerned with the error.

```
def SimpleSymbols(str_): 

    str_ = str(str_)
    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    str_list = list(str_)
    str_len= len(str_list)
    #print str_list
    #print str_len
    yesno = False
    first = True
    once = True

    dex = -1
    for i in str_list:
        #print 'step 1'
        dex = dex + 1
        dex_up = dex + 1
        dex_dwn = dex -1
        #print 'dex ', dex, 'dex_up ', dex_up, 'dex_dwn ', dex_dwn
        if i in letters:
            #print 'step 2 its a letter'
            if dex_dwn > -1:
                #print 'step 3 and its not the first letter'
                if dex_up < str_len:     
                    #print 'step 4 and its not the last letter'           
                    if str_list[dex_up] == '+':
                        #print 'step 5 checked, we got a plus in front'
                        if str_list[dex_dwn] == '+':
                            #print 'step 6 checked we got a plus in back'
                            yesno = True
                        else:
                            #print 'step 6 checked, no plus in back'
                            once = False
                    else:
                        #print 'step 5 checked, no plus in front'
                        once = False
                elif dex_up == str_len:
                    first = False
                    #print 'step 4 its the last letter'
            elif dex_dwn == -1:
                #print 'step 3 its the first letter'
                first = False

    if first and once == True:
        return yesno
    else:
        return False
print SimpleSymbols(raw_input())
```

this is the error i get from coderbyte:

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/py_compile.py", line 117, in compile    raise py_excpy_compile.PyCompileError: SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('prog.py', 48, 24, 'print SimpleSymbols(+g+)\n'))
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with coderbyte, but you may have discovered a bug.  Your code, while ugly and inefficient looks syntactically correct.  This line does however look like the culprit: `print SimpleSymbols(raw_input())`

Comment: i chnaged the function call to "print SimpleSymbols('raw_input()')" and it works in the test field, but when i submit the code it says its wrong. and to add insult to injury the arguments that it says failed work in the analyze section below. i give up. i give myself a A+

Comment: I just went back to coderbyte, but I realized I quit, because there were so many of these silly issues there.  I think what they intend for you is to quote the string in the input area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with your code.  For whatever reason, the coderbytes website makes you add quotes to the string that will replace the `raw_input()` call.

```
'+g+'
```

Works.

```
+g+
```

Gives a traceback.

Don't ask me why they implemented it like this.  `raw_input()` *should* always return a string, but instead they're doing some sort of `s/raw_input\(\)/whatever I typed into the form field/` operation, which is an unintuitive hack.

Comment: i chnaged the function call to "print SimpleSymbols('raw_input()')" and it works in the test field, but when i submit the code it says its wrong. and to add insult to injury the arguments that it says failed work in the analyze section below. i give up. i give myself a A+

Comment: No, I mean that you have to add quotations to what you enter *in the form field*.  Don't change your code.

Comment: my code works in my terminal. coderbyte is being inconsistent. i think its a bug. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to identify if a character in a string has specific characters
>   in front and behind it.

FWIW, a *[regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#module-re)* will make this much easier :-)

> I'm more concerned with the error.

The error is in your function call.
It should be:

```
print SimpleSymbols('+g+')
```

There need be quotation marks around the input string.